# Chef remote file timeout connection

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a problem using chef.
I have stored my file in a internal repository.
When I launch the run of chef and I have a remote file instruction, chef shows this error:

```
   remote_file[c:\chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u80-windows64.exe]      action create[2017-02-02T17:01:54+01:00]
    INFO: Processing remote_file[c:\chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe] action create (c:/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_helper.rb line 82)
    [2017-02-02T17:11:58+01:00] ERROR: Timeout connecting to: http://myinternlrepository/ExternalPackages/content/com/oracle/java/jdk/7u80/jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe, retry 1/5
```

Of copy and paste the link into a browser, the file is downloaded correctly.
Ruby have all permission, and I try to disable firewall but remote_file works once on 5/6 attempts.

I use Chef 12.5.1 on Windows 7 pro sp1

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

this can be caused either by a firewall or a proxy.
You need to set proxy settings in `client.rb` file

```
# HTTP for environment behind firewall
# http://docs.opscode.com/config.html
# solo.rb and client.rb can use the same http_proxy settings
http_proxy "http://proxy.company.com:3128"
http_proxy_user "username"
http_proxy_pass "password"
```

Comment: I don't have any firewall or proxy server

Comment: I have re-configured my system network config, and now all works correctly.
Thanks  you :)